# probability of getting two pairs in poker

Tags: probability, poker

If it is assumed that all (52C5)
poker hands are
equally likely, what is the probability of being dealt
two pairs? (This occurs when the cards have denominations a, a, b, b, c, where a, b, and c are all distinct.

Here I am not getting why can't I solve the question as

(13C1)(4C2)(12C1)(4C2)(11C1)(4C1)

the actual answer is (13C2)(4C2)(4C2)(11C1)(4C1)

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Also, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637750/probability-of-getting-two-pair-in-poker?rq=1) exact same question. It would be useful next time if you could tell us where the question comes from: how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common mistake you are committing that has to be guarded against.

When you write $(13C1)(12C1)$ for choosing  $a's$ and $b's$, you double count ($ab$ and $ba$)

We need to directly choose a pair , $13C2$ since we are not concerned with the order in which they were chosen